# Unattended authorisation to Google API in Go

Tags: go, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth, google-compute-engine

I've been trying to find a way to interact with Google's API (specifically, the Compute Engine API) without having the user authorise via a consent screen each time I need to reauthorise with Google.

The requests will be made when no user is present, so not having to authorise via a consent screen is an absolute must.

I'm using Go and the Go API Client Library.

Can anybody explain a method to achieve what I need to?

Comment: have you read https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2, the section about Applications on limited input devices

Comment: What is triggering the re-authorise request?  Is the original authorisation timing out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take a look at service accounts. They utilize the public/private key pair to authorize calls to Google API.

Google Developers has one very nice document explaining how service accounts work:

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount

Here's how generate a service account:

https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/#serviceaccounts

You will also find the code samples in the first doc, but unfortunately not in Go.
However, there are some comments that I found here:

https://code.google.com/p/google-api-go-client/wiki/GettingStarted

Hope it helps.